# C# Create a list and display a item in message box

Tags: c#, string, list

**I want to create a code that when button 1 is clicked :**

1. creates a list with items (ex : 1,2,3)
2. choose a random item in list (ex: 2)
3. display the item (in this case "2")in a message box

**Someone knows how can i do it ?
Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Random _random = new Random();

public void DoIt()
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>(){1 ,2, 3};
    int pos = _random.Next(list.Count);
    MessageBox.Show(list[pos]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Creating a List with Items:**

```
List<string> AuthorList = new List<int>();    
//The following code snippet adds items to the list.

AuthorList.Add(1);    
AuthorList.Add(2);    
AuthorList.Add(3);
```

Alternatively, we can also pass an array of objects to create a List object. The following code snippet creates a List object from an array of integers.

```
// Create a List using Range    
int[] number= { 1, 2, 3 };    
List<int> numberRange = new List<int>(number);
```

**Choosing Random Item in List:**

First Create an instance of Random class somewhere. Note that it's pretty important not to create a new instance each time you need a random number. You should reuse the old instance to achieve uniformity in the generated numbers. You can have a static field somewhere (be careful about thread safety issues):

```
static Random rnd = new Random();
```

Ask the Random instance to give you a random number with the maximum of the number of items in the List:

```
int r = rnd.Next(numberRange.Count);
```

**Display the number:**

```
MessageBox.Show((string)list[r]);
```

**When Button is clicked**

Just put all the code above into the ButtonClick Function

```
private void NumberGenerator_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{ }
```